# DWIM not installing when ActivePerl present

Tags: perl, strawberry-perl, activeperl

I have ActivePerl already installed but when now I am trying to install DWIM package, it is not openeing. Its installed but whenever I try to open the Padre IDE it gives the below error.

[image].

I read that we can have two Perl versions - ActivePerl and Strawberry Perl on the same system due to separate paths for them. This popup also came while installing while a command prompt window got open and then this popped up.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Padre problem rather than anything specific to your Perl install(s). Try uninstalling/reinstalling Padre... or try uninstalling Padre and installing Komodo: http://www.activestate.com/komodo-ide :-)

Comment: Reinstalling does not solves the problem, I don't want to install Komodo IDE, I want Padre and Strawberry Perl. It seems than in the end part of installing the script executes some command on command prompt but as ActivePerl is already installed, that command might be not going to the Strawberry Perl. I'll try different things to see if the problem can be resolved.